# How to send AMP Analytics in AMP story for links in bookend json

Tags: amp-html, amp-analytics, amp-stories

> **Background**

I have AMP page specifically [AMP stories](https://amp.dev/about/stories/) working great. Also the analytics is configured as shown bellow. The analytics for basic events like audio, bookend enter and exit, page view ... work great.

> **Problem**

Yet for the bookend configuration  shown in the second code below, I was un able to track link a href clicks that AMP generates from JSON.  I tried basic selectors for it, but that too doesn't work. Currently bookend is configured as a JSON. Is there a way to track click analytics for links in the bookend ? 
The documentation seems to be more on AMP pages.
 Since bookend is relatively new, I am worried that there is analytics support for it.

```
              <amp-analytics>
            <script type="application/json">
                                {
                              "vars": {
                                "storyURL": "${sourceUrl}",
                                "type": "story_analytics",
                                "templateId": "<%= @template_id %>",
                                "storyId": "<%= story.id %>",

                                "selectorGamedayURL": "amp-story-bookend",
                                "userId": "CLIENT_ID(site-user-id-cookie-fallback-name)"
                              },
                              "requests": {
                                "endpoint": "<%= AMP_ANALYTICS_URL %>",
                                "base": "${endpoint}"
                              },
                              "triggers": {
                 "anchorClicks": {
                    "on": "click",
                    "selector": "div.i-amphtml-story-bookend-article.i-amphtml-story-bookend-component",  // This doesn't work. the selector is correct but no analytics is sent 
                    "request": "event",
                    "vars": {
                      "event_id": "bookend-link-click"
                    }
                  },
                                "storyPageVisible": {
                                  "on": "story-page-visible",
                                  "request": "base",
                                  "extraUrlParams": {
                                    "event_id": "story_page_impression",

                                    "story_progress": "${storyProgress}",
                                    "story_page_index": "${storyPageIndex}",
                                    "story_page_count": "${storyPageCount}",
                                    "story_page_id": "${storyPageId}",
                                    "story_id": "${storyId}",
                                    "template_id": "${templateId}",
                                    "story_url": "${storyURL}",
                                    "timestamp": "${timestamp}",
                                    "type": "${type}",
                                    "user_id": "${userId}"
                                  }
                                },
                                "trackPageView": {
                                  "on": "visible",
                                  "request": "base",
                                  "extraUrlParams": {
                                    "event_id": "story_impression",

                                    "story_id": "${storyId}",
                                    "template_id": "${templateId}",
                                    "story_url": "${storyURL}",
                                    "timestamp": "${timestamp}",
                                    "type": "${type}",
                                    "user_id": "${userId}"
                                  }
                                },
                                "bookendEnter": {
                                  "on": "story-bookend-enter",
                                  "request": "base",
                                  "extraUrlParams": {
                                    "event_id": "story_bookend_enter",

                                    "story_progress": "${storyProgress}",
                                    "story_page_index": "${storyPageIndex}",
                                    "story_page_count": "${storyPageCount}",
                                    "story_page_id": "${storyPageId}",
                                    "story_id": "${storyId}",
                                    "template_id": "${templateId}",
                                    "story_url": "${storyURL}",
                                    "timestamp": "${timestamp}",
                                    "type": "${type}",
                                    "user_id": "${userId}"
                                  }
                                },
                                "bookendExit": {
                                  "on": "story-bookend-exit",
                                  "request": "base",
                                  "extraUrlParams": {
                                    "event_id": "story_bookend_exit",

                                    "story_id": "${storyId}",
                                    "template_id": "${templateId}",
                                    "story_url": "${storyURL}",
                                    "timestamp": "${timestamp}",
                                    "type": "${type}",
                                    "user_id": "${userId}"
                                  }
                                },
                                "audioMuted": {
                                  "on": "story-audio-muted",
                                  "request": "base",
                                  "extraUrlParams": {
                                    "event_id": "story_audio_muted",

                                    "story_id": "${storyId}",
                                    "template_id": "${templateId}",
                                    "story_url": "${storyURL}",
                                    "timestamp": "${timestamp}",
                                    "type": "${type}",
                                    "user_id": "${userId}"
                                  }
                                },
                                "audioUnmuted": {
                                  "on": "story-audio-unmuted",
                                  "request": "base",
                                  "extraUrlParams": {
                                    "event_id": "story_audio_unmuted",

                                    "story_progress": "${storyProgress}",
                                    "story_page_index": "${storyPageIndex}",
                                    "story_page_count": "${storyPageCount}",
                                    "story_page_id": "${storyPageId}",
                                    "story_id": "${storyId}",
                                    "template_id": "${templateId}",
                                    "story_url": "${storyURL}",
                                    "timestamp": "${timestamp}",
                                    "type": "${type}",
                                    "user_id": "${userId}"
                                  }
                                }
                              },
                              "transport": {
                                "beacon": true,
                                "xhrpost": true,
                                "useBody": true,
                                "image": false
                              }
                            }

            </script>
          </amp-analytics>
```

The Bookend JSON looks like this

```
              <amp-story-bookend layout=nodisplay>
            <script type="application/json">
              {
                "bookendVersion": "v1.0",
                "components": [
                {
          "type": "small",
          "title": "<%= title %>",
          "url": "<%= url %>",
          "category": "astronomy",
          "image": "<%= image_url %>"
          }
                ]
             }

            </script>
          </amp-story-bookend>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not yet available... You can track progress on this (and other analytics) here: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/12191

Comment: We got this work prioritized and tracked more specifically here: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/23893
Once it works, you should be able to keep the current snippet you posted here :)

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can track this using the recently introduced trigger: `story-bookend-click` as seen [in this PR](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/pull/24368).

To use it, just add this to your configuration:

```
              "trackBookendClicks": {
                "on": "story-bookend-click",
                "request": "click",
                "vars": {
                  "eventId": "clickOnBookend"
                }
              },
```

and in your request you can send variables like:
`"bookendClick": "${base}?bookendTargetHref=${storyBookendTargetHref}&bookendCardType=${storyBookendComponentType}&bookendCardPosition=${storyBookendComponentPosition}"`

Hope this helps!